# How to access a class attribute based on the value of another attribute of the same class?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have built the following code to understand Object Oriented Python.

```
class dog:
    def __init__(self, name, age):
        self.name = name
        self.age = age

def big(*args):
    return(max(args))

h = dog('Hello',5)
y = dog('Yellow',7)
print("The eldest dog is {} years old".format(big(h.age,y.age)))
```

Output:

```
The eldest dog is 7 years old
```

I want to know the name of the elder dog too. How do I refer the name from the big() function? Or by any other way?

Comment: You can't, you just get an integer back. If you wanted to get the "biggest" *instance*, determined by one of its attributes, you'd have to allow e.g. `big(h, y, attr="age")` (although I'd recommend taking an iterable rather than `*args`), it look it up again afterwards based on the age you get back.

Comment: Just for the sake of being pedantic: in Python, we don't say "class members", we say "attributes" (and, in this case, "instance attributes").

Answer (score 1):

You can't access a variable if you don't have a reference to that variable.

You can however make a list of all your instances and then do

```
max(dogs, key=lambda x: x.age)
```

to get the oldest dog from that list.

Comment: Or `key=operator.attrgetter('age')`

Comment: @bereal I believe that `lambda` is more common and used in more cases than `operator.attrgetter`.

Comment: `attrgetter` is ~25% faster according to my measurements, though.

Comment: @bereal Thanks, didn't know that. May use that later on huge lists.

Comment: s/variable/attribute/

Comment: @bruno Thank you for trying to correct me, but I was talking about the variables as in the instances(Hello and Yellow) not their attributes.

Comment: @MaxxikCZ AOK, my bad :oops: